# Webmatrix fails to connect PHP website to MySQL

Tags: php

1. I downloaded the latest versions of Webmatrix and MySQL.
2. I downloaded a PHP-MySQL Connector: 
   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/
3. In the "Databases" Workspace I pressed "New Connection" button and choose "MySQL Connection"
4. In the Dialog box I filled-in all connection details

--> It looks like the database was added.

But then when I double-click on the database, I get a short error message saying it cannot connect.

I tried everything, searched the web... I'm sure it's a very simple question, so please whoever can help I'll be grateful. I think best solution for me would be if someone could please just give me a link to download of: Webmatrix,MySQL,Connector; and instructions on how to install and then how to connect. This would be the safest way to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/forums/128313-webmatrix-suggestions/suggestions/2967632-feature-for-verify-the-connectionstring-instead-of

They will make a feature in near future that you can use to validate them.

To just check this can you try to use MySQL workbench.